# .htaccess redirect subdomain to a page in parent domain + query

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all (dynamic)subdomains to a page with querystring but it's giving page not found error.
Any ideas pls?
Eg. Would like something like

```
http://foo.example.com
```

to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/pagefile.php?member_id=foo
```

I would appreciate if it retains the subdomain URL format.

```
# Make PHP code look like other code types
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp .py .pl


    <Files php.ini>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mivasite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/pagefile.php?member_id=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the capture groups in your rewritecond and rewriterule. The matches in RewriteCond are stored in `%1`, `%2`, etc... while `$1`, `$2` etc... are the captures from RewriteRule.

You're not doing any capturing in the RewriteRule, so $1 will be blank. Try doing

```
RewriteRule .* http://mivasite.com/pagefile.php?member_id=%1
```

instead. Of course, That probably won't fix your 404 error, as this will merely fix up the query parameter. Check your server's error log to see exactly what the URL was that produced the 404 error.

Comment: Now the RewriteRule is giving 500 Internal Server Error when you type www.mivasite.com. Anyone please??

Comment: Look in the error log. It'll have the reason for the 500 error. Looking at the log files should always be the FIRST thing you do.

Comment: @Frank Does it make a difference if you add `[R=301,L]` flags at the end of rule?

Comment: it sees www as a subdomain hence will try to load http://mivasite.com/pagefile.php?member_id=www

Comment: Ah, so it's doing an infinite redirect? You'd want to explicitly exclude `www.mivasite.com` and `mivasite.com` from the rewritecond